# Can I install ubuntu on my mi pad?

Tags: tablet

I have a mi pad. can I install ubuntu on it?? or better can I dual boot it?

Further I read about installing ubuntu on a hard disk and connecting it to any device. can I do that on a sd card and boot my mi pad with that?

Comment: According to [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fpXmVzxl6JA) Youtube video you can.

Comment: it is for ipad. I  am asking about an androifd Xiaomi mi pad.

Comment: Almost one year has passed. Did you find a way to install Ubuntu on MiPad yet?

Comment: No. I didnt find it. It is not officially supported.